# Deploy custom policies with Azure Pipelines changing the charset encoding

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-devops) article to deploy my custom policies. I have enabled localisation in policies and providing translations for English and Spanish. By deploying manually there is no issues. But while using pipeline to deploy, my Spanish translation getting some issue:

My actual text is "Tu Teléfono Celular" but after deployment its "Tu Tel�fono Celular"

Comment: Have you tried using Azure AD Powershell? just try it ans we can check if the bug is in the Pipeline or the powershell  https://blog.medium.com/use-power-shell-to-upload-and-download-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-6fd1786057f1

Comment: Are you using explicit UTF-8 encoding with signature/BOM mark? if not, this might solve this particular issue, but might lead to issues with other components in the process.

Comment: Hi @Alex. You might try `$policycontent = Get-Content $PathToFile -Encoding UTF8`. I have also had to escape the file content previously for upload as well.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett Doesn't worked for me.

Comment: I tried to print the $policycontent after reading the file, it is showing the special characters as it is. So i guess the issue is with

```$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphuri -Method Put -Body $policycontent -Headers $headers```

So tried to pass content-type as utf-8 in header too, that also doesn't worked.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett i tried to write the file to a blob container that works fine, so the issue is with graph API for upload the policy to B2C.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue while deploying with Azure Pipelines.

I got a solution for this after doing trail and error method on deployment script.

I have changed the line in the script below.

from

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphuri -Method Put -Body $policycontent -Headers $headers
```

To

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphuri -Method Put -Body $policycontent -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
```

This change fixed the issue