# Does the Azure AD B2C Graph endpoint support UTF-8 charset for uploading policies?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy XML document that contains characters that need UTF-8 to be rendered correctly (A country name of Curaçao)

When I manually run my CI scripts which use UTF-8 and upload the policy to Azure B2C's UI, I see the characters as expected.

However, despite reading the file using the UTF-8 encoding, when I call the `graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustframework/policies/` endpoint for my PUT request, the resulting policy appears to not be rendered using UTF-8.

I have attempted the following for my content headers

- `$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/xml')` -- the original, where I first saw the problem
- `$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8')` -- no change
- `$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/xml; charset="UTF-8"')` -- 500 error from server
- `$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/xml; charset=utf-8')` -- the issue still persists.

Any thoughts? I'm sure it must be something I'm missing.

The full powershell excerpt of what I'm doing:

```
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/xml; charset=utf-8')
    $headers.Add("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + $token)

    $graphuri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustframework/policies/' + $PolicyId + '/$value'
    $policycontent = Get-Content $PathToFile -Encoding UTF8
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphuri -Method Put -Body $policycontent -Headers $headers
```

Image of the result:

[image]

Comment: `application/xml; charset=utf-8` is the correct content type. And `utf8NoBOM` is the default encoding of [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1). Please share more about your error.

Comment: Hi @PamelaPeng, thanks for following up! Using the ccontent-type exactly as you specify within my powershell, the issue is that the special character is stripped out (I've added an image of the result on the web page drop-down to the question). I am able to manually upload a policy via the UI where this is correct, and AFAICT in the script above I'm passing a UTF-8 file to an API with UTF-8 charset specified but the result of the API call is the image above.

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's not being uploaded correctly? Your browser may simply not be displaying UTF-8. Have you tried reading back the policy from the API endpoint?

Comment: @HongOoi it's a fair question. The reason I think the API is not getting the information correctly is that the same XML file, run through the same transformation script, does not have any issue when uploaded via the Azure B2C UI for custom policies. But the same file, when uploaded via the API via the script I note above, has the issue.

Comment: Thanks and it is mentioned in the xsd/schema to support utf-8 charset and here is the document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta and https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd. However Please share the correlation id or request id with timestamp to investigate more.

Answer (score 1):

The following post helped: [Deploy custom policies with Azure Pipelines changing the charset encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551789/deploy-custom-policies-with-azure-pipelines-changing-the-charset-encoding)

Change

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphuri -Method Put -Body $policycontent -Headers $headers
```

To

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphuri -Method Put -Body $policycontent -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
```